# Filling in blank spaces in the first column of a csv file using Bash / awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I am looking into automating some processes / calculations but I may first need to format a slightly awkward **CSV** file set. (For this I am using `bash`, as requested).

The csv file set follows (roughly) the format below

```
CODE,Sitting,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Totals
CLLK_J9,First Sitting,,,2,5,2,,,10
,Second Sitting,,,,,,,,1
RTHM_A8,First Sitting,,,1,,3,,,6
,Second Sitting,,,,,1,,,1
FFBJ_FA9,First Sitting,,,,8,6,,,25
,Second Sitting,,,,,11,,,12
UUYIOR_HJ9,First Sitting,,,1,3,6,,,17
IKRO_Lk8,First Sitting,,,,3,3,,,37
,Second Sitting,,,,6,11,,,34
```

[image]

I am trying to fill in the empty fields in the column `CODE` with the content of the field from the previous line (ordinarily these empty fields occur next to a "second sitting" instance in column 2). So, for the above example, the result should be like

```
CODE,Sitting,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Totals
CLLK_J9,First Sitting,,,2,5,2,,,10
CLLK_J9,Second Sitting,,,,,,,,1
etc.
```

I am starting to read some `awk` documentation as it seems a reasonably powerful utility for this task - but haven't made any progress yet. Thoughts?

ta

Comment: A textual representation of the file will help answerers test their solutions.  Also, bash is a shell, not a text editor -- it can call the eventual solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is very simple. Running

```
mlr --csv fill-down -f CODE input.csv >output.csv
```

you will have

```
+------------+----------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+
| CODE       | Sitting        | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Totals |
+------------+----------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+
| CLLK_J9    | First Sitting  | -   | -   | 2   | 5   | 2   | -   | -   | 10     |
| CLLK_J9    | Second Sitting | -   | -   | -   | -   | -   | -   | -   | 1      |
| RTHM_A8    | First Sitting  | -   | -   | 1   | -   | 3   | -   | -   | 6      |
| RTHM_A8    | Second Sitting | -   | -   | -   | -   | 1   | -   | -   | 1      |
| FFBJ_FA9   | First Sitting  | -   | -   | -   | 8   | 6   | -   | -   | 25     |
| FFBJ_FA9   | Second Sitting | -   | -   | -   | -   | 11  | -   | -   | 12     |
| UUYIOR_HJ9 | First Sitting  | -   | -   | 1   | 3   | 6   | -   | -   | 17     |
| IKRO_Lk8   | First Sitting  | -   | -   | -   | 3   | 3   | -   | -   | 37     |
| IKRO_Lk8   | Second Sitting | -   | -   | -   | 6   | 11  | -   | -   | 34     |
+------------+----------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Great to know about mlr!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try it with `awk`, the following should work:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' 'FNR>1{if ($1!="") last=$1; else $1=last}1' input.csv
```

This will set input and output field separators to `,`.

Then, for every line *after the first line* (`FNR>1`), it will check if the first column (`$1`) is empty. If it is not, the value will be stored in the variable `last` for later use. If it is empty, it will be filled with the previously stored value.

The `1` outside the rule block `{ ... }` instructs `awk` to print the current line including all modifications made. Note that unless this command (or actually any boolean condition evaluating to `true`) is specified, or an explicit `print`/`printf` command is given inside a rule block, `awk` will not print the current line.

Result:

```
CODE,Sitting,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Totals
CLLK_J9,First Sitting,,,2,5,2,,,10
CLLK_J9,Second Sitting,,,,,,,,1
RTHM_A8,First Sitting,,,1,,3,,,6
RTHM_A8,Second Sitting,,,,,1,,,1
FFBJ_FA9,First Sitting,,,,8,6,,,25
FFBJ_FA9,Second Sitting,,,,,11,,,12
UUYIOR_HJ9,First Sitting,,,1,3,6,,,17
IKRO_Lk8,First Sitting,,,,3,3,,,37
IKRO_Lk8,Second Sitting,,,,6,11,,,34
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an AWK solution, but...

```
$ cat yourfile.csv | csv-sqlite 'select code, (select i2.code from input i2 where i2.code != "" and i2.rowid <= i1.rowid order by i2.rowid desc limit 1) as new_CODE, Sitting, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Totals from input i1' -s
CODE         new_CODE     Sitting          Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Totals
CLLK_J9      CLLK_J9      First Sitting                2     5     2                 10
             CLLK_J9      Second Sitting                                             1
RTHM_A8      RTHM_A8      First Sitting                1           3                 6
             RTHM_A8      Second Sitting                           1                 1
FFBJ_FA9     FFBJ_FA9     First Sitting                      8     6                 25
             FFBJ_FA9     Second Sitting                           11                12
UUYIOR_HJ9   UUYIOR_HJ9   First Sitting                1     3     6                 17
IKRO_Lk8     IKRO_Lk8     First Sitting                      3     3                 37
             IKRO_Lk8     Second Sitting                     6     11                34
```

(if you'll drop "-s" it will come back as CSV)

csv-sqlite comes from https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools

Query was stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18990087/13998061).

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $1==""{$1=p} {p=$1} 1' file
CODE,Sitting,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Totals
CLLK_J9,First Sitting,,,2,5,2,,,10
CLLK_J9,Second Sitting,,,,,,,,1
RTHM_A8,First Sitting,,,1,,3,,,6
RTHM_A8,Second Sitting,,,,,1,,,1
FFBJ_FA9,First Sitting,,,,8,6,,,25
FFBJ_FA9,Second Sitting,,,,,11,,,12
UUYIOR_HJ9,First Sitting,,,1,3,6,,,17
IKRO_Lk8,First Sitting,,,,3,3,,,37
IKRO_Lk8,Second Sitting,,,,6,11,,,34
```